# Java naming convention for identifiers that begin with a number

Tags: java, naming-conventions, classname

I have to deal with a domain object that's real name is 351K-Report. According to the Java naming convention its forbidden to use a number at the beginning of an identifier.

I don't want to fully spell out the number. And, I also think that it's a bad idea to place an underline in front of the number.

But what is the recommended alternative?

**UPDATE**

There are also other reports, like SpecReport, TopReport, LF10Report and so on. So I'm very doubtful that inverting parts of the noun changes the meaning of the whole project.

Comment: What about.. `report`?

Comment: what about: `Report351K`

Comment: It's not against convention per se, it's disallowed by Java's syntax.

Comment: I feel that the reverse order changes the meaning and the subject of the report significantly. Are there other smarter ideas?

Comment: Maybe it would help us to know the meaning behind "351K"?

Comment: Its a domain specific fixed noun describing a threshold. But naming it 351KThresholdReport also doesn't solve the naming problem. Maybe Treshold351KReport, but it also sounds a little bit strange.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe reverse it. For example:

```
report351K
```

Comment: If '_' is not suitable and reversing is out of question then there is one more option. You can use $ as first character. This is very unconventional but allowed.
$351KReport

Answer (score 1):

That would be very bad..

Imagine this:

```
int 1d = 3;
double d = 1d * 2;
```

What would be `d`?

Alternatives:

Since variables that begins with `_` usually indicates for *class member*, I would use `report351K`.

Comment: That's not really an answer at all. They already know they shouldn't start it with a number, that's why they've asked the question. Saying simply "anything" is not helpful.

Answer (score 0):

if you really want to do this then `_351KReport` but I don't think you should do this. try to make something meaningful of it and at the same time is convineient to Java